# How to send the string which is part of URL from volley?

Tags: android, json, authentication, android-volley

It may be dumb question but i struck with this am making simple login application using volley need to post String which is part of URL like this http://xxx.xx.x./{user_id}/{passwrd} and need to get json response from server so far what i have tried is :

```
private void registerUser(final String s, final String s1){
        Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        jsonParams.put("email", s);
        jsonParams.put("username", s1);

        JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String yog=response.toString();
                        Log.e("Yog",yog);
                        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }


                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,s);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,s1);

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

and calling this method inside onclick listener don't know where am making mistake can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private String tag_json_obj = "jobj_req";

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);


    String Url="http://x/x/x/x/Login?user_email=er.naveen,tamrakar@gmail.com&password=123123123";
                        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                                Url, null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                        mResponseTextView.setText(response.toString());
                                        hideProgressDialog();
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                hideProgressDialog();
                            }
                        }) {

                            /**
                             * Passing some request headers
                             * */
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                return headers;
                            }


                        };

                        // Adding request to request queue
                        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
                                tag_json_obj);

    private void showProgressDialog() {
            if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.show();
     }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.hide();
     }






public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }



    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Url="http://x/x/x/x/Login?user_email=er.naveen,tamrakar@gmail.com&password=123123123";

Comment: get value when onclicklistner will call

Comment: what is appcontroller

Comment: where u r geting NPE

Comment: i resolved it am getting response but cannot post the value to the parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
     private void postDatalogin(String Usermail, String Userpwd,
                           String Devicetype, String Deviceid, String osname, String version, String ip) {
    /* XMl Http Post */
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = null;
    httpPost = new HttpPost(
            Loginurl);

    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Usermail));


    //nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_information",Deviceinfo));
    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        String strRet = HttpHelper.request(response);
        Log.d(strRet, "strstrRet");
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(strRet);
            String result = jsonObjRecv.getString("status");
            Log.d(result, "result");
            String message = jsonObjRecv.getString("info");
            Log.d(message, "message");
            String userid = "", username = "", useremail;
            if (result.equals("Success")) {
                userid = jsonObjRecv.getString("userid");
                useremail = jsonObjRecv.getString("email");
                username = jsonObjRecv.getString("username");
                Log.d(userid, "userid");
                SharedPreferences app_preferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences1.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("login", true);
                editor.putString("userid", userid);
                editor.putString("usermaiid", useremail);

                editor.commit();
                hidepDialog();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                    }
                });


            } else {
                hidepDialog();
                showalert(message);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

just append your password in the URL  http://xxx.xx.x./myId/mypass  the params can be null or no value

Comment: can you share  it its getting volleyserver exception

Comment: i can't see any problem in your code... is the URL working in your browser??

Comment: did you try to use stringrequest instead of JsonObjectRequest

Comment: its working i just append the urser id and pwd to url its working fine thnq @kevin Lorena